Подключение базы данных postgresql в XAMPP
Я пишу проект, в котором использую php (XAMPP) и postgresql.
Через var_dump я проверил, что база данных действительно подключена. Однако код вызывал ошибку 500. Тогда я вывел ошибку на экран и получил следующее: Call to unknown function: 'pg_connect'
Я пробовал несколько разных способов скачать эту библиотеку на macos (в основном, brew install), но ничего не помогло. Как мне решить эту проблему?

Сервер перегружать пробовали после установки через brew?

Во-первых, если вы пользуетесь какой-то панелькой управления, то подключать расширения надо средствами этой панельки. Л - Логика. ищите в своем "XAMPP", где там подключаются функции postgres.

Во-вторых, совершенно непонятно, что означает фраза "Через var_dump я проверил, что база данных действительно подключена."  var_dump какой переменной вы делали, что именно она вам вывела, учитывая, что никакого соединения в принципе быть не могло?
